# Writing to the file in unix

Tags: files, io-redirection, echo

I'm facing some problems in writing to the file in unix

```
[ -s $PWD/MEN/*sub.wav ] && echo "File there" || echo "File Not there" > temp.csv
```

I'm trying this unix command
but it is not writing to the file temp.csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break your command then these is equivalent

```
[ -s $PWD/MEN/*sub.wav ]
```

It will execute anyway if your pattern "$PWD"/MEN/*sub.wav doesn't matches more than a single filename. Then comes

```
echo "File There"
```

The shell try to execute this command and in your case it had executed sucessfully and then comes `||`This means that if left part fails then execute right part. As our left part is executed then right part will never be executed. If you want to write **File there** to temp.csv then your command look like

```
[ -s $PWD/MEN/*sub.wav ] && echo "File there" > temp.csv || echo "File Not there" > temp.csv
```

or if you want to write both part then

```
[ -s $PWD/MEN/*sub.wav ] && echo "File there" > temp.csv && echo "File Not there" > temp.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

The only thing writing to `temp.csv` in your command is the last `echo`, which only gets executed if the `-s` test or the first `echo` fails.

To output to the file properly do

```
if [ -s MEN/*sub.wav ]; then echo "File there"; else echo "File not there"; fi >temp.csv
```

or (not quite equivalently),

```
[ -s MEN/*sub.wav ] && echo "File there" >temp.csv || echo "File not there" >temp.csv
```

Also note that if your pattern `MEN/*sub.wav` matches more than a single filename, this would generate a syntax error in your program.

Would you want to test whether *at least one* name matches the pattern, and is non-empty (the `-s` test), then use

```bsh
set -- MEN/*sub.wav

# Loop over the matching names (if any).
# Stop when we find a non-empty file.
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ ! -s "$1" ]; do
     shift
done
if [ -s "$1" ]; then
    echo File exists
else
    echo File not there
fi >temp.csv
```

Would you want to test whether *all* names that match the pattern are non-empty:

```bsh
set -- MEN/*sub.wav

# Loop over the matching names (if any).
# Stop when we find an empty file.
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && [ -s "$1" ]; do
     shift
done
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo File(s) exists
else
    echo File(s) not there
fi >temp.csv
```

This last piece of code relies on the shell retaining the unexpanded pattern in case there are *no* matching names.